# sticky/draggable video on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-canvas

When a user plays the video and starts to scroll through a page or a post, the video player will pinned from the primary position to the position of the reader’s screen set by you. So the video remains viewable even while scrolling to a different part of the webpage.

Example: (try to play the video on the right)
https://www.cnet.com/news/

[image: Scroll]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to check at which position the `video`element is. You can do this with the `jquery` function `scrollPos()`

To give you an idea how you can achieve this ive created a fiddle. The fiddle is very simple. Just to give you the basic idea.

You can edit this to your own needs.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 
  var scrollTop = $(".container").scrollTop();
  
  $(".container").scroll( function() {
   var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   
   if(scrollTop > 155) {
     $(".video").animate({
        "height": "100px",
        "width": "200px",
      });
      $(".video").css({
       "position": "fixed",
        "top": 20, "right": 40,
      });
    };
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container .video {
  background: #ededed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. 
    </p>
    <div class="video-container">
      <div class="video">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. 
    </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut efficitur felis ut nibh aliquet tristique. Quisque vel pretium enim, eget euismod libero. Donec ipsum dui, fermentum sed turpis dictum, iaculis blandit velit. 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simple library for this purpose, maybe it helps.

https://github.com/afuggini/sticky_video